# hyperledger fabric: "peer" not recognized during channel creation & joining - first network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been roughly following http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#troubleshoot to create my first network.

For simplicity, I had made a separate folder, *mn* inside *first-network*, and had started with only *crypto-config.yaml*, *cryptogen*, *configtx.yaml*, *configtxgen*, *docker-compose-cli.yaml* and *base* folder in *mn* folder, to observe what is created when, also to eliminate bin path confusion.

I have executed the following commands in the same sequence:

```
./cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml

./configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block

 ./configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID testhimani

 ./configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID testhimani -asOrg Org1MSP

 ./configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID testhimani -asOrg Org2MSP

 docker exec -it cli bash
```

After executing the last command, I had to open a new terminal window, [as I couldn't get the command input "$"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Xh9.png).

On the new terminal, on executing the channel creation and joining command, I received the error that "peer" command is not found.

```
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~/fabric-samples/first-network/mn$ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c testhimani -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
No command 'peer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pee' from package 'moreutils' (universe)
 Command 'pear' from package 'php-pear' (main)
 Command 'peet' from package 'pipexec' (universe)
 Command 'beer' from package 'gerstensaft' (universe)
peer: command not found
```

**UPDATE**
The error after executing the command in the same terminal after # instead on a new terminal, is the following:

```
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~/fabric-samples/first-network/pg$ docker exec -it cli bash
root@0404332355e0:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c testhimani -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
Usage:
  peer channel create [flags]

Flags:
  -c, --channelID string   In case of a newChain command, the channel ID to create.
  -f, --file string        Configuration transaction file generated by a tool such as configtxgen for submitting to orderer
  -t, --timeout int        Channel creation timeout (default 5)

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
  -v, --version                             Display current version of fabric peer server
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I feel orderer is missing in my docker ps. How can I take care of it?

```
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~/fabric-samples/first-network/pg$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
0404332355e0        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest   "/bin/bash"         2 days ago          Up 2 days                                                              cli
68075835c9f9        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest    "peer node start"   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
8a76208f8411        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest    "peer node start"   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
87a73761dfc7        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest    "peer node start"   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
9ab8cbc25f99        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest    "peer node start"   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
```

Comment: How do you start up your docker containers? Have you defined de orderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you execute

> docker exec -it cli bash

you will get new tty of cli you are using. And you will bee prompted with # instead of $ in the same terminal.

If you open a new terminal window, it still be your system cli.

As per your screenshot, you are on the right path. And that is where you have to execute the next command.

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion but there's a new error now, after trying what you said. please see the update

Comment: If you have not changed anything in docker-compose-cli.yml for your BYFN, the orderer should be defined there. By using docker-compose up, you can bring that up.

Comment: Something had gone wrong with running byfn.sh file. It is rectified now, and it is working. orderer is also seen in docker images

Comment: Great. Have fun.